# Speed up code finding difference between every 12th element in a vector

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I have a vector with a length over 200,000. For simplicity, say it is:

```
x <- c(1:96)
```

What I want to do is generate a vector containing the difference as between a number and the next twelfth number in the vector. In this case it would generate a vector like so:

```
diff <- c( (13 - 1) = 12, (14 - 2) = 12, (15 - 3) = 12, ...)
```

I am hoping that this example makes sense (just for description). Currently, I am running the following for loop to generate it:

```
diff <- c()
for (k in 1:length(x)){
   d <- x[k+12] - x[k]
   diff <- c(diff, d)
}
```

This is generating what I want, but it is running very slow for large vectors. If anyone has suggestions on how to speed this up, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Just do this: `tail(x, -12L) - head(x, -12L)`. It's vecorized.

Comment: Thank you so much lmo, this is exactly what I needed

Comment: Also `diff(x, 12)`.

Comment: `diff` is faster, the results are `identical()`.